# Saving swift enum without raw value in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, enums

**1 Is there any way to store swift enums without `rawValue` in core data?**
e.g. This enum:

```
enum ConnectionState {
    case connecting, failed, connected, disconnected, blocked
}
```

If there way for above enum, then again,
**2 Is there any way to store swift enum with associated values in core data?**
e.g. This enum:

```
enum ConnectionState {
     case connecting, failed(Error), connected, disconnected(Error), blocked
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, there is no way, Core Data supports only a few types.

In both cases you can use computed properties to convert an enum to a Core Data compliant type and vice versa.